# Sequelize: Return associated results array without embedded objects

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

With this query:

```
const noteRecords = await db.job_notes.findAll({
  attributes: [],
  include: [
    {
      model: db.jobs,
      attributes: [],
      where: {
        id: jobId,
      },
    },
    {
      model: db.notes,
      attributes: ['id', 'body'],
    },
  ],
});
```

Sequelize returns results as:

```
[
   {
      "note": {
         "id": "2",
         "body": "Lorem Ipsume Dolor Sumut"
      }
   },
   {
      "note": {
         "id": "3",
         "body": "Sum es est sumus estis sunt"
      }
   }
]
```

While I want it to return as:

```
[
  {
     "id": "2",
     "body": "Lorem Ipsume Dolor Sumut"
  }, 
  {
     "id": "3",
     "body": "Sum es est sumus estis sunt"
  }
]
```

Aside from `noteRecords = noteRecords.map(note => note.note)` is there a Sequelize way to do get the data formatted in this way?

Answer (score 0):

Solved by changing the query to:

```
const noteRecords = await db.notes.findAll({
  include: [
    {
      model: db.jobs,
      attributes: [],
      where: {
        id: jobId,
      },
    },
  ],
});
```

Since my association in db.notes is:

```
models.notes.belongsToMany(models.jobs, {
  through: 'job_notes',
  foreignKey: 'note_id',
  sourceKey: 'id',
});
```